# "Хуже" - вводное слово?

Tags: вводные-слова

Нужна ли указанная запятая?

В итоге через некоторое время на этом объекте при его эксплуатации может случиться авария или (,) хуже, катастрофа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге через некоторое время на этом объекте при его эксплуатации может случиться авария или, хуже, катастрофа.

ХУЖЕ. Ещё хуже; хуже того, в зн. вводн. словосоч. Употр. для усиления, выделения чего-л.

Союз "или" - разделительный, поэтому перед ним нет запятой.